# Regex for 4-Block-Pattern combined with min and max lentgh

Tags: java, regex

I a have a formular that is in **4-Block format** (e.g.  1232 2131 3233 2323 23).

What I want is to check an input String, if it machtes this pattern BUT with a maximum length.

I have found a way for a **fixed length**....e.g. **".{4} .{4} .{2}"** for fixed length 10 (the whitespaces should not count to length)

But how has the regex to look like if I want to check the 4-Block-pattern for a variable length with a max count of charactrs.

Let´s say **4-Block for max-length of 10 characters** which would allow all of these: "XXX", "XXXX", "XXXX XX", "XXXX XXXX", "XXXX XXXX " and "XXXX XXXX XX".

I try to build a java function with that signature:

```
public static String getRegex(int blockSize, int maxLength) {

}
```

Thank you for your mindpower.

Comment: Please include some examples of the various length types of matches you expect here.

Comment: Lets say I have a MaxLength of 10. Then I need to allow "XXX", "XXXX", "XXXX XX", "XXXX XXXX" and "XXXX XXXX ". How would that regex look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can group signs using parenthesis. And giving two numbers in {} with comma between means min and max occurs. For situation you mentioned: (.{4} .{4}){1,2}.
So it would check whether it is:
XXXX XXXX
or
XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX
If you want check if only this pattern is in string you should also add '^' at the beginning and '$' at the end.
Then it should look like:
^(.{4} .{4}){1,2}$

^ means beginning of a line
$ means end of a line

Comment: Nice, but lets say I have a MaxLength of 10. Then I need to allow "XXX", "XXXX", "XXXX XX", "XXXX XXXX" and "XXXX XXXX ". How would that regex look like?

Comment: Oh, now I get what you want. I would do that in some steps. Maybe there is a better way. I would calculate how many times at least and at most whole 4-block occurs. It can be done by a=floor(minLength%5) and b=floor(maxLength%5). So I get something like that: "(.{4}){a,b}" . But there can still be charaters left (from 1 up to 4 cause we divided by 5 hence last 4 chars without space which is 5th char can also be). So I would check this like that "(.{4}){a,b}( .{1,4}){0,1}" and separately check the length of string.

Answer (score 0):

I would first calculate the max length *including possible whitespaces*, which depends on the number and the size of the blocks. So say for a block size of 4:

- if max length is 7, max number of whitespaces is 1 (XXXX XXX)
- if max length is 8, max number of whitespaces is 1 (XXXX XXXX)
- if max length is 9, max number of whitespaces is 2 (XXXX XXXX X)

This can be generalised as follow:

```
int numberOfWhitespacesAllowed = (maxLength - 1) / blockSize;
int maxLengthIncludingWhitespaces = maxLength + numberOfWhitespacesAllowed;
```

Now we know this, we can more easily build the regex, by first checking the general pattern:

```
^(\S{<blocksize>}\s)*\S{1,<blocksize>}$
```

For example for a block size of 4:

```
^(\S{4}\s)*\S{1,4}$
```

And then adding the check for the max length by using a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?=.{1,<maxLengthIncludingWhitespaces>}$)
```

For example for a max length (including whitespace) of 9:

```
^(?=.{1,9}$)(\S{4}\s)*\S{1,4}$
```

All together in Java:

```
public static String getRegex(int blockSize, int maxLength) {
    int numberOfWhitespacesAllowed = (maxLength - 1) / blockSize;
    int maxLengthIncludingWhitespaces = maxLength + numberOfWhitespacesAllowed;
    return "^(?=.{1," + maxLengthIncludingWhitespaces + "}$)(\\S{" + blockSize + "}\\s)*\\S{1," + blockSize + "}$";
}
```

Which gives for block size of 4:

- for max length of 7: `^(?=.{1,8}$)(\S{4}\s)*\S{1,4}$`
- for max length of 8: `^(?=.{1,9}$)(\S{4}\s)*\S{1,4}$`
- for max length of 9: `^(?=.{1,11}$)(\S{4}\s)*\S{1,4}$`